# Rotation of necklaces

Tags: combinatorics, necklace-and-bracelets

The number of fixed necklaces of length $n$ with $a$ types of beads is
$$N(n,a)=\frac1n\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)a^{n/d}\;.$$
It is clear intuitively that the number of rotational coincidences gets proportionally negligible for the large number of beads. How to prove it? Any estimation to calculate?

Comment: Do you know [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma)?

Comment: Yes, I hear about it, thank you, but how to apply it? It results in the number of fixed necklaces.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prove? $\frac{\phi(1)a^n}{n N(n,a)} \to 1$?

Comment: Thank you. The question come from comparison of 2 necklaces. Could you have a look at the comments by leonbloy please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140504/comparison-of-two-very-large-necklaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A necklace that has no rotational symmetry is called a *primitive* or *aperiodic* necklace, or a *Lyndon word* (if written as a word by taking the lex-smallest rotation.)  The number of primitive necklaces is given by almost the same formula as the one you give for the number of necklaces, but with Euler's $\phi$ replaced by the Mobius function $\mu$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)#Aperiodic_necklaces)): $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d |n } \mu(d) a^{n/d}.$$

Intuitively, we would expect that for large $n$ a random necklace would be almost surely be primitive, since there would have to be a large number of coincidences to find a rotational symmetry.  To prove this, just take the ratio

$$\frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d |n } \mu(d) a^{n/d}}{ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d |n } \phi(d) a^{n/d}} = \frac{a^n + O(a^{n-1}) }{ a^n + O(a^{n-1}) }$$

since the highest order terms in both polynomials corresponds to $d=1$, and $\mu(d) = \phi(d) = 1$.  Then the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ is $1$.

Comment: Thank you, Jair! I still can't cope with other necklace problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2968031/approximation-of-products-of-necklaces